# gitignore across all branches?

Tags: git, gitignore

Hey I'm trying to get into git, as an emacs user first thing to do is to make sure the ~ and #*# files are ignored by git. Documentation talks about .gitignore which I've been using. However couple of questions remain:

- gitignore is now checked in and part
  of a branch. Should .gitignore be
  checked in and if so, how can i make
  it easy available across all branches
  in my repository?
- is there a way to
  use the gitignore with git config so
  gitignore stays constant over all my
  repos?
- How can I deal with emacs lock
  files as #*# is treated as a comment?

I'm on mac ox snow leopard.
regards,
Jeroen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your `$HOME/.gitconfig` ;

```
[core]
    excludesfile = /path/to/your/local/.gitignore
```

Then it'll be locally available on all your git repositories.

Comment: Is there a way to make it global (one for all branches) without making it local (it will still push/pull to/from remote origin)?

Comment: This is answer to OP's second question which makes it applicable to all local repos. 


Is there a way to ignore some files *across branches of a single repo* ? This was OP's first question and that's what I'm also looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you created the gitignore file before creating the branches, it's obviously available in them. Otherwise you need to merge that file to other branches.

You can define a global ignore file with git config --global core.excludesfile [ignorefile].

Comment: merging a (set of single) file(s) is done best with: http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/ ?

Answer (score 2):

- http://cogniton-mind.tumblr.com/post/1423976659/howto-gitignore-for-different-branches
- You can create a global gitignore

create a `~/.gitignore` in your user directory

```
.DS_Store 
*.pyc 
.svn
```

then run:  `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`

- Emacs files

  \#*#

Since 1.6.2, `\` should be supported in `.gitignore`

Answer (score 1):

1. Check-in the .gitignore file. It is available across all the branches (unless you mess about with it) and keep it up to date with all your exclusions
2. Use a global gitignore file.
3. Add this to your gitignore file.

   *#

   .#*

I've written about the [three ways of excluding files here](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/519016351/three-ways-of-excluding-files).

Comment: It is only available in the branch committed to, and in those branches into which you merge this commit.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to get that file into all branches would be probably git cherry-pick commit with .gitignore file into those branches

Comment: I dont think cherry-pinking the "add .gitignore file commit" into all branches is what @dr jerry is after since he is asking for a method to make the file available _across  all branches_. Sure, the file will be available in all branches after cherry picked, but it would still be branches specific because changes to the file will not be shared across branches without further merging/cherry-picking.